# PIL resizing image

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

image.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)

PIL sets the height of the new image to the size given(128 here) and calculate the width to keep the aspect ratio.

Is there a way to set width to 128 and let it calculate height to keep the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation thumbnail method:

```
Modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size.
```

Try setting width to 128 and using a big number (e.g. 10000) for height.

Answer (score 1):

well if all else fails, you can always just use python directly as the calculator:

```
width_ratio = image.size[0]/128.0
new_height = image.size[1]/width_ratio
```